# VBA Finding row value from Vlookup function

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Im trying to get the row number back after matching the user input via Vlook up this is meant to be used in the process of pulling items into a custom userform for editing. How should i return this Row number.
Here is my code for this.

```
Sub Sheet1_Button2_Click()
Dim Vall As String

Vall = InputBox("Enter Refernce #", Find & Edit)
Vall2 = Application.VLookup(Vall, 11, K1)
MsgBox "found" & Application.Row(Vall2)
Vall3 = Vall2.Rows

UserForm1.TextBox1 = Sheets(1).Range("A" + Vall3).Text
UserForm1.TextBox2 = Sheets(1).Range("B" + Vall3).Text
UserForm1.TextBox3 = Sheets(1).Range("C" + Vall3).Text
UserForm1.TextBox4 = Sheets(1).Range("D" + Vall3).Text
UserForm1.TextBox5 = Sheets(1).Range("E" + Vall3).Text
UserForm1.TextBox6 = Sheets(1).Range("J" + Vall3).Text
UserForm1.TextBox12 = Sheets(1).Range("K" + Vall3).Text
UserForm1.TextBox7 = Sheets(1).Range("M" + Vall3).Text
UserForm1.TextBox8 = Sheets(1).Range("N" + Vall3).Text
UserForm1.TextBox10 = Sheets(1).Range("O" + Vall3).Text
UserForm1.TextBox11 = Sheets(1).Range("P" + Vall3).Text

UserForm1.Show



End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps use `MATCH()` instead?

Comment: You can't get a row number from `VLOOKUP` because that function returns a value, not a `Range`. If you need a row number, use a function that returns a row number - like `MATCH`.

Comment: Also make sure your module says `Option Explicit` at the very top - you don't want to be using undeclared variables, accidentally or not. e.g. `Find & Edit` probably means to be enclosed in double quotes as a string literal; as it stands, it's understood as the concatenation of two undeclared `Variant/Empty` values, and your inputbox title is an empty string.